# Setup inputView for different UITextFields in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield, inputview

I have `UITableView` with `UITextField`s in custom cells.

For `UITextField` I use custom `inputView`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Item

        cell.price.text = ""
        cell.price.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.inputView = keyboardView
        itemPrice = textField
    }

func numberWasTapped(number: String!) {
        itemPrice.insertText(number!)
    }
```

With delegate method:

```
@IBAction func keyTaped(sender: UIButton) {
      switch sender.tag {
        case 112:
          if !isCommaWasPressed {
             isCommaWasPressed = true
             sender.enabled = false
             self.delegate?.numberWasTapped(sender.titleLabel!.text)
           }
           break
       default:
           self.delegate?.numberWasTapped(sender.titleLabel!.text)
       }
```

My custom `inputView` is the calculator keyboard with the all logic in the Keyboard class: it controls if comma was pressed and how many numbers was entered after the comma.
For example, if comma was pressed, then `commaButton.enabled = false` in Keyboard class.

I couldn't figure out how to set the `commaButton.enabled = true` in Keyboard class when I'm switching to another `UITextField`.

I tried `textField.reloadInputViews()` in 
`textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)` method but it doesn't work.

I think, I should get the information from `UITextField` and pass it to Keyboard's class logic. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What your saying is, after clicking a different cell from the previous one you need to change some property on the previous cell, which in this case is the commaButton.enable, right?

Comment: Hi @diogo-antunes.

Comment: Hi @diogo-antunes.
`commaButton` is the `UIButton` in custom `inputView` for `textField` in a cell.
`commaButton` is declared in Keyboard class.
Keyboard class has delegate method:
`@IBAction func keyTaped(sender: UIButton) {
switch sender.tag {
case 112:
            if !isCommaWasPressed {
                isCommaWasPressed = true
                sender.enabled = false
                self.delegate?.numberWasTapped(sender.titleLabel!.text)
            }
            break
default:
self.delegate?.numberWasTapped(sender.titleLabel!.text)
}
`

Comment: Updated description of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I moved keyboard logic to main ViewController and no need to pass textField data to Keyboard class.